# How to achieve unique _id value in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I am using Python2.7, Pymongo and MongoDB. I'm trying to get rid of the default _id values in MongoDB. Instead, I want certain fields of columns to go as _id.

For example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568f7df5ccf629de229cf27b"),
    "LIFNR" : "10099",
    "MANDT" : "100",
    "BUKRS" : "2646",
    "NODEL" : "",
    "LOEVM" : ""
}
```

I would like to concatenate LIFNR+MANDT+BUKRS as 100991002646 and hash it to achieve uniqueness and store it as new _id.

But how far hashing helps for unique ids? And how do I achieve it?

I understood that using default hash function in Python gives different results for different machines (32 bit / 64 bit). If it is true, how would I go about generating _ids?

But I need LIFNR+MANDT+BUKRS to be used however. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you *can't update the `_id` field*. Instead you should create a new field and set it value to the concatenated string. To return the concatenated value you need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. The only stage in the pipeline is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator which concatenates strings and returns the concatenated string.
From there you then iterate the cursor and update each document using  ["bulk"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html) operations.

```
bulk = collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
count = 0
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {"$project": {"value": {"$concat": ["$LIFNR", "$MANDT", "$BUKRS"]}}}
])

for item in cursor:
    bulk.find({'_id': item['_id']}).update_one({'$set': {'id': item['value']}})
    count = count + 1
    if count % 200 == 0:
        bulk.execute()
if count > 0:
    bulk.execute()
```

---

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates `Bulk()` and its associated methods so you will need to use the [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) method.

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne


requests = []
for item in cursor:
    requests.append(UpdateOne({'_id': item['_id']}, {'$set': {'id': item['value']}}))
collection.bulk_write(requests)
```

---

Your documents will then look like this:

```
{'BUKRS': '2646',
  'LIFNR': '10099',
  'LOEVM': '',
  'MANDT': '100',
  'NODEL': '',
  '_id': ObjectId('568f7df5ccf629de229cf27b'),
  'id': '100991002646'}
```